# CONTAINS("HP:H-P:NA.Co",Company) function returns true even if Company name is "-","NA" and "."

Tags: formula-field, string, contains

I need advice in writing Contains function while using the Formula field.

```
CONTAINS("HP:H-P:NA.Co", Company)
```

function should return true only if it matches the exact substring `H-P` or `NA.Co` in this case.
Please let me know if any other in-built functionality can be used in place of Contains to match the company names

Answer (score 0):

The expression which you have written will only evaluate to true if values will exactly match with Company name.
According to your requirement you should try this:

```
CONTAINS(Compoany, "HP") || CONTAINS(Compoany, "H-P") || CONTAINS(Compoany, "NA.Co")
```